# How can I tell a custom UIView with UITextField receive touch events

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, uilabel

What I'm working with is I have a custom UIView that combines a UILabel with a UITextField as part of some user input. I have several of these throughout the view that is being displayed in the app. What would be good is to be able to have the user touch either the UILabel or the UITextField and then have the UITextField allow for input of the field.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tap gesture recognizer to your label, and when tapped tell the corresponding textfield to become first responder (which brings up the keyboard).

```
    // In your init or awakeFromNib:
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped:)];
    self.label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.label addGestureRecognizer:tap];

...

- (void)labelTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it only seems to work for one of the custom UIViews. The other on the page doesn't accept any taps.

Comment: You should be adding this code in your custom UIView subclass, so it should apply to all instances of that subclass. It sounds like you are adding this code in the ViewController...

Comment: It's in the UIView subclass. If the frame or bounds of the view weren't correctly set, would that produce the behaviour I'm seeing?

Comment: Okay, was my bad. I had some overridden methods to try and handle touches in the UIView subclass as well. When I removed those, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is and I actually tested it. You can add a tap gesture recognizer to your view (the one that contains the label and the text view) like so:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:[tap autorelease]];
```

and then, inside `viewTapped:`

```
-(void)viewTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to restrict that tap area to be just the custom UIView rather than the whole window? I have multiple of these views on the screen at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said... You can add a tap gesture recognizer to your view, the one tat contains the label an the text view. Unlike the other answer, if you add the tap gesture to your custom view, the textView will allow for input even if the user taps outside the label but inside the custom view.

Comment: If the UITapGestureRecognizer is added to self rather than the UILabel, any taps within the window of the device will focus to the text field. This isn't the behaviour I'm after.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to the app's window. In this case 'self' is referring to the custom view. I tested the answer before I posted it and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `UIGestureRecognizer` delegate method and check that is the the required tap gesture area . If it is then return TRUE else return FALSE .

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
    if ((touch.view == yourButton)) {//change it to your condition
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: touch.view == yourButton compares the pointers not the objects.what you mean is  isEqual: function